# How do I start developing applications for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi
I would like to learn and develop applications for iPhone. Can some one guide me on where to start? I'm new to mobile application development. I have good exp in developing web applications and desktop client applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started With iPhone Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development)

Comment: See also [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: Learn to to search forums for already asked questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a mac. An intel based mac is
   required. Basically you need Mac OS
   X.
2. Learn C, Objective-C.
3. Get the iPhone SDK.
4. Get a good book on it. Do the examples.
5. Check out the Stanford Learning Series on iTunes, where you can virtually take the course at Stanford. Do the homework assignments, etc...

Comment: Good call on the Stanford courses. They also have a course on introductory C programming which is excellent.  I find the videos to be a bit slow paced, but if you have the time they are a great free resource.

Comment: Thanks, Is it so that you need to get a mac OS? can't we do it on windows XP?

Comment: In order to use Windows, you'll need VMWare and modified Mac OS X iso's (which aren't legal).  I plan on purchasing a refurbished iMac, but a mac mini should suffice you as well.  They run around $500.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any experience with C?  If not, you should probably start there, then work into learning objective-C, and finally dive into the Apple frameworks (i.e. Cocoa touch).

apple has good documentation at http://developer.apple.com

If you prefer books, I would  highly recommend [iPhone Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242) by Aaron Hilligrass:

Also note that you are free to write iPhone apps and test them on a simulator, but to actually push code to a real device you need to purchase a developer profile for $99

Comment: +1 The Conway & Hillegass book is a fine tome. (As is Hillegass' Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X.)

Comment: I picked up that book recently and it's fantaqstic.  Got the Kindle version on my iPad - it's a great way to learn.

Comment: Pretty good advice, except I wouldn't recommend starting with learning C. You can write decent apps only knowing Obj-C, but you'd have a hard time writing anything if you only know C. Plus, you'll learn a significant chunk of C along the way, as you learn Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

As darren has said you'll want a good knowledge of C. You can go along the C#/ objective C route but theres also the Airplay SDK. If you have a good knowledge of C apprently you can make games for iPhone quite easily, not had the chance to try it out yet but looks promising. According to the site COD: Nazi Zombies was made using it, might be worth a look.

http://www.airplaysdk.com/

Comment: What do you mean by C# route?  I'm curious, I've never heard C# mentioned with OSX/iPhone programming.

Comment: MonoTouch lets you program apps for the iPhone in C#, but if you are just starting out in mobile development, learning Obj-C is the way you would want to go. Stuff like MonoTouch only really benefits folks who know C# and don't want to learn Obj-C.